# Google Firestore Quota Exceeded on free account

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm on the free trial of Google Firestore, and out of no where I can query any data or even see it on my Google Cloud Platform. I didn't know there was a cap? Where can I find information about how much I'm allowed to use on a free trial? And how do I upgrade my current project so I can access my data again?

This is what is responding with

```
{
"error": {
"code": 429,
"message": "Quota exceeded.",
"status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/). From there the quota for Cloud Firestore the Spark/free plan are:

```
Stored data        1 GB total
Bandwidth          10GB/month
Document writes    20K/day
Document reads     50K/day
Document deletes   20K/day
```

To upgrade click the <kbd>Upgrade</kbd> button in the bottom left of your [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/overview).